# SQl datatype length

Tags: java, sql, sqldatatypes

```
package drivers;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main implements ActionListener
{
    private JFrame f;
    private JLabel lb_name,lb_email,lb_address,lb_hourlyrate,lb_startdate,lb_enddate,lb_reason,lb_homeph,lb_cellph,lb_image;
    private JTextField tx_name,tx_email,tx_address,tx_hourlyrate,tx_startdate,tx_enddate,tx_homeph,tx_cellph;
    private JButton bt_go,bt_next,bt_image;
    private JTextArea txf_reason;
    private ImageIcon ic;
    private JPanel p;

    public String s="";

    public Main()
    {
        f=new JFrame();
        lb_name=new JLabel("Name");
        lb_email=new JLabel("E-mail");
        lb_address=new JLabel("Address");
        lb_hourlyrate=new JLabel("Hourly Rate");
        lb_startdate=new JLabel("Starting Date");
        lb_enddate=new JLabel("Enddate");
        lb_reason=new JLabel("Reason of Quiting");
        lb_homeph=new JLabel("Home Phone");
        lb_cellph=new JLabel("Cell Phone");
        tx_name=new JTextField();
        tx_email=new JTextField();
        tx_address=new JTextField();
        tx_hourlyrate=new JTextField();
        tx_startdate=new JTextField();
        tx_enddate=new JTextField();
        txf_reason=new JTextArea();
        tx_homeph=new JTextField();
        tx_cellph=new JTextField();
        bt_image=new JButton("Browse");
        bt_image.addActionListener(this);
        bt_go=new JButton("Go");
        bt_go.addActionListener(this);
        bt_next=new JButton("Next");
        bt_next.addActionListener(this);
        ic =new ImageIcon(s);
        lb_image=new JLabel();
        lb_image.setIcon(ic);
        p=new JPanel();
        p.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.LineBorder(new java.awt.Color(255,255,255), 1, true));
    }

    public void launch()
    {

        f.setLayout(null);
        f.setSize(630,470);
        f.add(lb_name);
        f.add(lb_email);
        f.add(lb_address);
        f.add(lb_hourlyrate);
        f.add(lb_startdate);
        f.add(lb_enddate);
        f.add(lb_reason);
        f.add(lb_homeph);
        f.add(lb_cellph);
        f.add(tx_name);
        f.add(tx_email);
        f.add(tx_address);
        f.add(tx_hourlyrate);
        f.add(tx_startdate);
        f.add(tx_enddate);
        f.add(txf_reason);
        f.add(tx_homeph);
        f.add(tx_cellph);
        f.add(bt_go);
        f.add(bt_next);
        f.add(p);
        p.add(lb_image);
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        lb_name.setBounds(20,30,50,30);
        tx_name.setBounds(60,30,150,30);
        bt_go.setBounds(270,30,60,30);
        lb_email.setBounds(20,110,40,30);
        tx_email.setBounds(130,113,200,25);
        lb_address.setBounds(20,140,50,30);
        tx_address.setBounds(130,143,200,25);
        lb_hourlyrate.setBounds(20,170,70,30);
        tx_hourlyrate.setBounds(130,173,60,25);
        lb_startdate.setBounds(20,200,80,30);
        tx_startdate.setBounds(130,203,150,25);
        lb_enddate.setBounds(20,230,80,30);
        tx_enddate.setBounds(130,233,150,25);
        lb_homeph.setBounds(20,260,80,30);
        tx_homeph.setBounds(130,263,100,25);
        lb_cellph.setBounds(20,290,80,30);
        tx_cellph.setBounds(130,293,100,25);
        lb_reason.setBounds(20,320,100,30);
        txf_reason.setBounds(130,323,200,70);
        bt_next.setBounds(400,380,60,40);
        p.setBounds(350,100,220,240);
        tx_email.setEditable(false);
        tx_address.setEditable(false);
        tx_hourlyrate.setEditable(false);
        tx_startdate.setEditable(false);
        tx_enddate.setEditable(false);
        tx_homeph.setEditable(false);
        tx_cellph.setEditable(false);
        txf_reason.setEditable(false);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Main m=new Main();
      m.launch();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource().equals(bt_go))
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:project","sa","123456");
                String s=tx_name.getText();
                Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name,address,email,startdate,enddate,reason,homeph,cellph,hourlyrate,image FROM driver");
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    if(s.equals(rs.getString(1)))
                    {
                        tx_address.setText(rs.getString(2));
                        tx_email.setText(rs.getString(3));
                        tx_startdate.setText(rs.getString(4));
                        tx_enddate.setText(rs.getString(5));
                        txf_reason.setText(rs.getString(6));
                        tx_homeph.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(7)));
                        tx_cellph.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(8)));
                        tx_hourlyrate.setText(Integer.toString(rs.getInt(9)));
                        s=rs.getString(10);
                        ic=new ImageIcon(s);
                        lb_image.setIcon(ic);
                        lb_image.setBounds(350,100,200,200);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(f,ex);
            }
        }
        else if(e.getSource().equals(bt_next))
        {
            enter en=new enter();
            en.launch();
            f.hide();
        }
        else if(e.getSource().equals(bt_image))
        {
            String s;
            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.showDialog(jfc, "Choose an image file");
            s = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
            imagePath.setText(s);
        }
    }

}
```

i am searching a name from database and displaying it's information on the frame on the basis of name entered so and there's also a frame which is entering the values to the database. i took varhcar(10) as datatype of name. for e.g. if i enter the rahul in name then it is stored as rahul with 5 spaces after it('rahul    ').so when i search the database through rahul name it won't display the data until i enter 5 spaces after it. which datatype should i use so as to have length same as that of length of name typed???

This is my SQL insert code

```
INSERT INTO [project].[dbo].[driver]
           ([Name]
           ,[Address]
           ,[Email]
           ,[Hourlyrate]
           ,[Homeph]
           ,[Cellph]
           ,[Startdate]
           ,[Enddate]
           ,[Reason]
           ,[Image])
     VALUES
           (<Name, varchar(20),>
           ,<Address, varchar(50),>
           ,<Email, varchar(25),>
           ,<Hourlyrate, int,>
           ,<Homeph, bigint,>
           ,<Cellph, bigint,>
           ,<Startdate, varchar(30),>
           ,<Enddate, varchar(30),>
           ,<Reason, varchar(50),>
           ,<Image, varchar(200),>)
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the relevant parts.

Comment: ignore the code....study the information i provided..

Comment: Can you redefine the database? Because when you insert something in the database complet with space, that is a failure in the definition of the database. The other way is when you search complet the name that you type with space until the length.

Comment: @Deckard27 i m inserting the name through textfield into database and in database it is saved with rahul and 5 spaces after it because i took varhar(10) as datatype of name but if i enter the values directly in database then everthing works fine rahul is stored as rahul with no extra space....

Comment: the tha database is perfect, ok i understand, to solve this complet the rahul that you type ti rahul with spaces.

Comment: @Deckard27 no i did not entered any space i only entered rahul...

Comment: I said that complete with space... concat space until the length is 10

Comment: What you need to do is in the INSERT query, wrap the Name field in an RTRIM()..that should remove the irrelevant spaces after the name. If i could see your insert statement code i could probably help a bit more

Comment: @DevN00B how to use this RTRIM ???

Comment: i mean in you question you say the Name is a value entered into a text box that you then enter into your database so it would be String Name = YourTextBox.getText(). Then you do a executeQuery(INSERT RTRIM(Name), blah, blah INTO Driver)